# Customers can't register anymore in magento webstore

Tags: php, magento

I'm running into a big problem here, i noticed that customers can't fill out a register anymore, when they do it just refreshes the page, the webaddress is: http://www.ittd.nl/magento/   and for register is: http://www.ittd.nl/magento/index.php/customer/account/create/

Could anyone please help me out here? I'm really troubled right now.

Greetings,
Clay

Comment: First, wrong stack exchange. Try the magento stack exchange for magento issues. Secondly, what have you done to troubleshoot the issue? Have you found any errors? What did google provide you? Typically you need to work on it before the public does.

Comment: i'm really sorry :(  i haven't found any errors, and i backupped the whole thing, google hasn't showed anything usefull,  i'm really sorry :(

Comment: Was Magento upgraded recently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you restored the involved template files?

app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml

Also check if there is a redirect set, I have worked with clients that do not want potential clients to be able to register without first calling or emailing the company, in which case a redirect was set to send the user back to the home page when the register button was clicked...

hope this helps and good luck troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your Javascript. Check in your Console and see if you can fix the errors. It's not sure that's why you have problem but you should try to resolve the errors. Is your form submission handled by Javascript?